# How can I make pbuilder use my apt-cacher-ng instance?

Tags: apt-cacher-ng, pbuilder

I have a [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) server on my LAN network, and I was wondering how I could "force" `pbuilder` to use it (to speed up package builds).

Typical setup client-side of the cache goes something like this:

In `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

`Acquire::http { Proxy "http://servername:3142"; };`

Comment: pbuilder has a `--mirror` option that i guess sets the mirror to use. Try setting it to apt-cache-ng server address.

Comment: @Salem I don't think that'd do it, since apt-cacher-ng is just a proxy not a mirror.

Comment: @jrg apt-cacher-ng can run as a mirror. Simply use `http://servername:3142/ubuntu` as your mirror url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ sudo pbuilder --login --save-after-login
# echo 'Acquire::http { Proxy "http://servername:3142"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
# exit
$
```

Alternatively, you could use the `--execute` option:

```
$ sudo pbuilder --execute --save-after-exec -- /tmp/setup-apt-proxy.sh
```

... where `/tmp/setup-apt-proxy.sh` contains commands to create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy`.

Comment: Will `servername` be found from the build environment? Shouldn't one use an IP address instead, since the proxy is most certainly local?

Answer (score 3):

If you set `export http_proxy=http://your-proxy:8080/` in `~/.pbuilderrc` it will use that proxy for the package downloads.

I just tried it on my setup, and it worked. As best I could tell from the internet traffic, I didn't have to download anything while running `pbuilder create`.

The nice thing is that this way also works when you are creating the tarball, not just after you create it and then modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the **--mirror** argument, eg:

```
sudo pbuilder create --debootstrapopts --variant=buildd --configfile ~/.pbuilderrc --mirror http://localhost:3142/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ main restricted universe multiverse
```

verify the caching hits on the proxy:

```
$ tail -f  /var/log/apt-cacher/access.log 
Thu Dec 19 19:16:33 2013|26140|::ffff:127.0.0.1|HIT|1272844|us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages.bz2
Thu Dec 19 19:18:45 2013|26647|::ffff:127.0.0.1|HIT|49563|us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release
Thu Dec 19 19:18:45 2013|26663|::ffff:127.0.0.1|HIT|198|us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release.gpg
Thu Dec 19 19:18:46 2013|26707|::ffff:127.0.0.1|HIT|1272844|us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages.bz2
```